# How do I achieve writing svg inside of cfscript tags?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, svg

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:
http://rickosborne.org/blog/2008/01/generating-scalable-stretchy-and-smart-graphics-with-coldfusion-part-2/
but inside   tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
savecontent variable="myVariable" { WriteOutput("Hello World"); }
```

quoted from: http://www.isummation.com/blog/cfsavecontent-in-cf9-cfscript/